# Why can't I use setResolutionSelector in CameraX although I have the latest camera package?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-camerax

I have an existing Android Mobile App developed in Java in Android Studio that I need to work on. The task includes changes to image resolutions of picture we take with Camera X. I looked into the API and found [setResolutionSelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.Builder#setResolutionSelector(androidx.camera.core.resolutionselector.ResolutionSelector)). This looked like the perfect function for what I want to accomplish, but when I start typing in Android Studio, the function is not offered to me.

[Function is offered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shgXw.png)

I am very new to Android Studio and Android development and I would like to know what I am missing.

According to the [Android site](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera), the latest version of Camera X is 1.2.2. I made sure, we are using the latest version in our project.

[Latest version of CameraX is in use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB7wt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the latest **alpha** version. Currently it's `1.3.0-alpha06`.

Comment: Thank you. I wish the Android documentation would show the required version for a function in its overview.